# 4 responsive buttons in the center of the page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'll like to have a div which contains 4 buttons with some margin in the center of the page. The div container and the buttons should be responsive. I have try using differing components from bootstrap to achieve this, but with no luck... The picture below illustrate how i'll like to arrange these buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .outer {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .inner {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: auto auto;
                grid-gap: 5px;
            }
            button {
                height: 10vh;
                width: 15vw;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                <button>Hello</button>
                <button>Hello</button>
                <button>Hello</button>
                <button>Hello</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .btn{
    height: 60px;
  }
 
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container-fluid bg-success">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-1 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-1 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-1 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-1 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
 </div>
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you :)

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
<div class="bg-primary p-2">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-2 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-2 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-2 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
  <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-light btn-block p-2 m-2" type="button">test</button></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```